# Job hangs forever with no logs

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

With the Python SDK, the job seems to hang forever (I have to kill it manually at some point) if I use the extra_package option to use a custom ParDo.

Here is a job id for example : `2016-12-22_09_26_08-4077318648651073003`

No explicit logs or errors are thrown...

I noticed that It seems related to the extra_package option because if I use this option without actually triggering the ParDo (code commented), it doesn't work either.
The initial Bq query with a simple output schema and no transform steps works.

Did it happen to someone ?

P.S : I'm using the DataFlow 0.4.3 version. I tested inside a venv and it seems to work with a DirectPipelineRunner

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Based on the worker logs in Cloud Logging for your job, it seems like perhaps your extra_package was binary-incompatible with Dataflow's packages, or something of this sort. Is the issue still happening or were you able to run the job successfully in the end? What was the package?

Comment: No worries, I confirm that. The requirements.txt in my root directory and the one in the extra_package were different. Causing the exec.go in DataFlow container failing again and again. I ended up recreating recreating the venv with the same frozen dependancies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As determined by thylong and jkff:

The extra_package was binary-incompatible with Dataflow's packages.  The requirements.txt in the root directory and the one in the extra_package were different, causing the exec.go in DataFlow container failing again and again. To fix, we recreated the venv with the same frozen dependencies.